# Orthogonality in different inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, orthogonality

Given a vector space V where two vectors *v* and *u* are orthogonal with respect to a given inner product. Will the same vectors be orthogonal with respect to all the other inner products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no. On $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider its usual inner product and also the inner product defined by$$\bigl\langle(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\bigr\rangle=2x_1y_1-x_1y_2-x_2y_1+x_2y_2.$$Then $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are orthogonal with respect to the usual inner product, but $\bigl\langle(1,0),(0,1)\bigr\rangle=-1$.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the orthogonality relation specifies an inner product up to a positive scalar multiple. To see this, suppose $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and $[ \cdot, \cdot ]$ are two inner products on a space $V$ with the same orthogonality relation. Note that if $V = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, then the two inner products must be the same, so otherwise $V$ contains non-zero vectors.

Let $w \in V$ be non-zero, and define $k_w = \frac{\langle w, w \rangle}{[w, w]} \in (0, \infty)$. Clearly, if $v = \lambda w$ for scalar $\lambda$, then $\langle v, w \rangle = k_w [v, w]$. Otherwise, if $v$ is independent from $w$, then
$$v - \frac{[v, w]}{[w, w]}w \perp w$$
under both inner products, in particular,
$$0 = \left\langle v - \frac{[v, w]}{[w, w]}w, w \right\rangle \implies \langle v, w \rangle = \frac{\langle w, w \rangle}{[w, w]} [v, w] = k_w [v, w].$$
By a corresponding argument, we can also formulate $k_v \in (0, \infty)$ instead, and show
$$\langle w, v \rangle = k_v [w, v],$$
which implies that $k_v = k_w$. This holds for linearly independent $v, w$ as well as linearly dependent $v, w$ as shown above. So $k_v$ and $k_w$ don't depend on $v$ and $w$ at all, and is in fact a constant. Thus, some $k \in (0, \infty)$ exists such that
$$\langle w, v \rangle = k [w, v],$$
as required.

Comment: You claim $v-[v,w]/[w,w]w\perp w$ under both inner products. While it's trivial for $[\cdot,\cdot]$, why is it the case for $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$?

Comment: @J-J By assumption, the orthogonality relations for each inner product is the same. So, orthogonality under $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is by computation, and hence the orthogonality under $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ follows by assumption.