# Equivalent norms in Hilbert spaces preserves orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $V$ be a real vector space [infinit dimensional] and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$ inner products on $V$. Also denote by $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ the respective norms induced by such inner products. Supose $||\cdot||_1$ is equivalent to $||\cdot||_2$. If $\langle u, v \rangle_1 = 0$, is it true that $\langle u, v \rangle_2 = 0$ ?

Comment: It is not true. If you pick two inner products, that aren't scalar multiples of each other, on your favourite vector space (infinite-dimensional, or not), then you should find a counterexample. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649128/orthogonality-in-different-inner-products/2649174#2649174) for a reason why a counterexample should exist in these circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. On $\ell^2$, let $\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<,>_1$ denote the standard inner product, define $$\<x,y>_2 := (x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2) + x_2y_2 + \sum_{ n\ge 3} x_ny_n $$
The induced norms are equivalent, but $\<e_1, e_2>_2\ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you! However in $L^2$ and $H^{1}_0$ this could work? That is, if $\int fg= 0$, then $\int \nabla f \cdot \nabla g = 0$ ?